# Multivariate analysis of sparse data

Tags: r, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, multiple-comparisons

I am analyzing data from a food preparation evolution over time. I have 13 dependent variables (`A` to `M`) and 3 independent variables (`Time`, `Treatment` (2 levels) and `Type` (2 levels)). Each case contains only two observations. The samples analyzed at each time point all come from the same lot but are otherwise independant.

I want:

1. To determine whether there is a degradation of the preparation in time, and the magnitude of this degradation;
2. To compare the preparations with or without treatment.

I go about doing this using the [r](/questions/tagged/r) `manova` function.

```
test = manova(cbind(A,B,C,D,E,F1,G,H,I,J,K,L,M)~Type*Treatment*Time,data =data.w)
summary(test)
```

I obtain the following:

[image]

Discarding the non-significant interactions:
[image]

So it looks like that:

1. The `Time`covariate has a significant effect
2. The `Treatment`has no significant effect

Now for my specific questions:

1. Is that the correct way to proceed to the analysis?
2. What of the low number of observations?
3. The `manova` function complains that `Estimated effects may be unbalanced`, where as I have the same number of observations in each case. Is that a case where I need to use a different SS?
4. How can I evaluate the magnitude of the `Time` effect?

Thanks for your help

PS: I happy to provide a reproducible example but was worried it would complicate an already cluttered question.